# Why does my div enlarge when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Long story short, I'm making a simple Tic Tac Toe game where Player1 clicks for his move, and Player2 dblclicks for his move. The Clear div is simply to clear the board. It's fairly simple. My only issue is the, when clicked, the Clear Div increases in height. It still works, but isn't attractive from an ascetic standpoint. What's going on?

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr></tr>
    <td><div class="dot"></div></td>
    <td><div class="dot"></div></td>
    <td><div class="dot"></div></td>
  <tr></tr>
    <td><div class="dot"></div></td>
    <td><div class="dot"></div></td>
    <td><div class="dot"></div></td>
  <tr></tr>
    <td><div class="dot"></div></td>
    <td><div class="dot"></div></td>
    <td><div class="dot"></div></td>
</table>
<body>
  <div id="clear">Clear</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
table{
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto;
  border-spacing:7px;
}
.dot{
  border-radius:50px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:#A8A8A8;
}
.playerOne{
  border-radius:50px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
.playerTwo{
  border-radius:50px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}
#clear{
  border-radius:50px;
  width:300px;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:#A8A8A8;
  text-align:center;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
}
#clear:active{
  border: 2px solid black; 
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('div').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('playerOne');
  });
  $('div').dblclick(function() {
    $(this).addClass('playerTwo');
  });


  $('#clear').click(function(){
    $('.dot').removeClass('playerOne');
  });
  $('#clear').click(function(){
    $('.dot').removeClass('playerTwo');
  });
```

});

Comment: Your table should be in the body, and the td's within tr's. You need to fix this first.

Comment: why is your `table` outside the `body`, which is not present in a standard HTML code?

Comment: You should put this code into http://jsfiddle.net/ so people can see it interactively.

Comment: Maybe the non-standard HTML causes some browser incompatibilities. It seems to work here in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/FvkLA/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two lines should be changed to

```
 $('.dot').click(function() {
     $(this).addClass('playerOne');
 });
 $('.dot').dblclick(function() {
     $(this).addClass('playerTwo');
 });
```

You were adding the player classes to any div on click, and the clear button was a div. the '.dot' selects anything with a class of 'dot'

Answer (score 1):

It likely increases in height by about.. 2-4px? This is because your `active` class adds this:

```
  border: 2px solid black;
```

To fix it you can add these values to the divs you want to dynamically add margin/padding to:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8bY2/)

I fixed your css styles. There were a lot of redondant properties.
And I add some properties to disable the selection on dblclick.
I cleaned up your javascript code also.

And I fixed your border issue (the solution of Formic does not work on my Chrome), by adding a transparent border to the `#clear` class. Then, when the border black appears the size stays the same.

```
#clear{
  border-radius:50px;
  width:300px;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:#A8A8A8;
  text-align:center;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); // here is the trick!
}
#clear:active{
  border: 2px solid black; 
}
```